# ManyToOne as ID on doctrine (symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm developing a project with Symfony2 LTS and need to create Entities for doctrine. In my database model I have a OneToMany relation, that is part of the PK.

```
Parent
+-------+--------------+-----+----------------+
| Field |     Type     | Key |     Extra      |
+-------+--------------+-----+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | PRI | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) |     |                |
+-------+--------------+-----+----------------+

MyChild
+--------------+---------+-----+----------------+
|    Field     |  Type   | Key |     Extra      |
+--------------+---------+-----+----------------+
| id           | int(11) | PRI | auto_increment |
| foreignId    | int(11) | PRI |                |
| other_fields | text    |     |                |
+--------------+---------+-----+----------------+
```

When I create a PHP Entity class only with id as `@ORM\Id` tehre are no Problems, but when I try to add the ManyToOne as Id I get an error

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                 
  Single id is not allowed on composite primary key in entity MyBundle\Entity\MyChild
```

The Php class looks like this:

```
class MyChild
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var MyParent
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyParent", inversedBy="childs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foreignId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $parent;
```

Comment: It makes no sense for MyChild to have a compound primary key.  Show how you made foriegnId or maybe look at some sql basics.

Comment: I'd like to start the incrementation of the Id of the child for each parent, so I need it as primary key. For example Parent 1 can have child 1-1,  1-2, ... and Parent 2 can have 2-1, 2-2, 2-3

Comment: And how exactly is that going to work with Child::id being an auto-inc?  Messing around with id's is almost always more trouble that it is worth.  What happens if 2-2 gets deleted?  Going to renumber everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the **@ORM\Id** from the $parent and create a UniqueConstraint for $id and $parent.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={
 *   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(
 *     columns={"id", "foreignId"}
 *   )
 * })))
 */
class MyChild
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var MyParent
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyParent", inversedBy="childs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foreignId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $parent;
```

Comment: Thanks that's almost perfect. Can I tell $parent to be NOT NULL?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, but I can set `nullable` on `JoinColumn`

Comment: So you should add @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foreignId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)

Comment: Great answer. And yes, the associations foreign key are `NULL` by default. You can see all the SQL query by running `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`